# Can I loop through logical operators in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

In order to avoid repetition, I would like to do something like this:

```
a, b = True, False
l = list()
for op in [and, or, xor]:
    l.append(a op b)
```

I tried `import operator` and also `itertools`, but they do not contain logical operators, just math and some other ones.

I could not find any previous answer that was helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example can be implemented using the `operator` module.

```py
from operator import and_, or_, xor

ops = [and_, or_, xor]
l = [op(a,b) for op in ops]
```

These are bitwise operators, but for booleans -- which are represented in only one bit -- they double as logical operators.

Answer (score 2):

`or` and `and` can't really be replicated by functions because they short-circuit; but if you don't care about that you can write lambda functions, e.g. `lamba x, y: x and y`. For xor on booleans you could use [`operator.ne`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.ne).

```
ops = [(lambda x,y: x and y), (lambda x,y: x or y), operator.ne]
l = [op(a,b) for op in ops]
```

The list comprehension was suggested by Adrian W in the comments.

Update: Use [stfwn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287248/3890632). It's better.

Comment: instead of a `for` loop, just say: `l = [op(a,b) for op in ops]`